# Mod Rewrite proxy to different backend hosts

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a virtual host with multiple `ServerAlias host1.example.com host02.example.com` etc.

I match the same pattern and based on `ServerAlias` I want to proxy them to different backend hosts. What I have is :

Snippet from config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host1.example.com [NC]
RedirectMatch  ^/~([^/]*)$ http://host01.example.com/~$1/';
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host01.example.com/$1/   [P]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host01.example.com/$1/$2 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host02.example.com [NC]
RedirectMatch  ^/~([^/]*)$ http://host02.example.com/~$1/';
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host02.example.com/$1/   [P]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host02.example.com/$1/$2 [P]
```

This works but only for the first defined ruleset. How can I make them both work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` only applies to the very next `RewriteRule`.  It never applies to a `RedirectMatch`.  Those are handled by `mod_alias` not by `mod_rewrite`.

To get this to work you will need to repeat your `RewriteCond` for each rule and use a `RewriteRule` in place of `RedirectMatch`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host1.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host01.example.com/$1/   [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host1.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host01.example.com/$1/$2 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host02.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host02.example.com/$1/   [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?host02.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule    ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-host02.example.com/$1/$2 [P]
```

I'm not sure exactly what your `RedirectMatch` is actually supposed to be doing, so I just removed it for now.

If you are using Apache 2.4 or later, you could wrap your `RedirectMatch` in an if block:

```
<If "req('Host') =~ /^(www.)?host1.example.com/">
    RedirectMatch  ^/~([^/]*)$ http://host01.example.com/~$1/';
</If>
```

I'm not sure if `RewriteRule`s are compatible with `<If>` or not.   You could try putting all of your rules inside those `<If>` blocks and forgoing the `RewriteCond` altogether.

Comment: It looks like the intention of `RedirectMatch` was to append a trailing slash (when there is just one path segment), however, there is an erroneous `';` on the original directive - so this may not be being used anyway? (And it should be a `RewriteRule` to ensure it executes early and can probably apply to all hostnames, so may not need a condition, depending on the `ServerAlias` config.)

Comment: @MrWhite any comments on my edit about the compatibility of rewrite and If?

Comment: Your edit looks OK to me... it will restrict the `RedirectMatch` directive to requests for that _Host_ only. The other mod_rewrite directives will be processed as normal (first). However, I think putting all the directives in the `<If>` - as you suggest - would be preferable. And change the `RedirectMatch` to `RewriteRule` in the process - this isn't a serious issue, as there is no conflict, but it is "confusing" as the directives are not processed in the order they appear in the file.

Comment: AFAIK, the only _issue_ with mod_rewrite and `<If>` containers is if you have mod_rewrite directives both inside and outside the `<If>` container and are expecting them all to be processed. If the mod_rewrite directives inside the `<If>` container are processed (because the if-expression is met) then these will completely overide the directives outside of the `<If>` container (by default)! In much the same way mod_rewrite directives in child `.htaccess` files completely override any parent `.htaccess` file (or `<Directory>` container). You can use mod_rewrite inheritance to overcome this.

Comment: However, these directives look as if they could be simplified - there may not be any need to duplicate these directives for each host if the naming of the hostnames is consistent. (I've added an answer/addendum.)

Comment: @MrWhite I knew you'd know the answers to those knotty questions.  I would not have expected that completely overriding behavior you describe.

Comment: Yes, it is not intuitive and I imagine is rarely what is required. This would seem to be because [`<If>` sections are merged last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging). However, having multiple `<If>` sections _that match_ seems to complicate matters further (module dependent)?

Answer (score 2):

This is really just an addendum to @Stephen's answer (which already appears to address the main problem).

However, your directives could possibly be greatly simplified. If you are using the "same patterns" for each rule block and your hostnames are consistent, ie. `host01.example.com` maps to `users-host01.example.com` etc. (Although you have a slight inconsistency in your first example: `host1` to `users-host01`?) Then there is no need to repeat your directives for each hostname.

Also, if you only have non-www hostnames in your `ServerAlias` then there is no need to check for the www subdomain in your directives. (But this should probably be canonicalised earlier if you are allowing this.)

So, your directives could potentially be simplified to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/~$1/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]*)/(.*)$ %{HTTP:X-Scheme}://users-%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [P]
```

Your first `RewriteRule` is superfluous as it is handled by the second (if there is nothing after the trailing slash then the `$2` backreference is simply empty).

As noted in comments above, your `RedirectMatch` directive had an erroneous `';` on the end of the target URL. This was also a temporary 302 redirect and should probably be a 301 (permanent). But only change this to a 301 once you have confirmed it works as expected.